# JS Как подружить select+option и localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage, html-select

Помогите разобраться.

Есть `select`, в зависимости от выбора пользователя в `id=contact_method` подставляются разные номера телефонов.

Теперь необходимо реализовать `localStorage` чтобы пользователю не приходилось на следующей странице опять выбирать значение из select.

Используя код ниже `localStorage` работает только для `option`, как исправить чтобы `localStorage` работал для `option` и `id=contact_method` одновременно?

```
<select id="contactSelect">
<option value="0">Россия</option>
<option value="1">Беларусь</option>
</select>
<p id="contact_method">+7</p>
```

JS
1) Функция для замены номера телефона в зависимости от выбора в select

```
 document.getElementById("contactSelect").onchange = function() {
        var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        if(value == '1') {
            document.getElementById("contact_method").innerHTML = '+375';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("contact_method").innerHTML = '+7';
        }
    }
```

2) Функция для localStorage

```
 document.getElementById("contactSelect").onchange = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('contactSelect', document.getElementById("contactSelect").value);
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem('contactSelect')) {
        document.getElementById("contactSelect").options[localStorage.getItem('contactSelect')].selected = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (localStorage.getItem('contactSelect')) {
  document.getElementById("contactSelect").options[localStorage.getItem('contactSelect')].selected = true;
  document.getElementById("contactSelect").onchange(); 
}
```

Несколько слов не для протокола, а "для души". Вы два раза присваиваете значение свойству `document.getElementById("contactSelect").onchange`. Второе присваивание, естественно, отменяет первое. Чтобы прикрепить несколько обработчиков к одному событию, используйте `addEventListener`:

```
function updateContactMethod() {
  var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  if(value == '1') {
    document.getElementById("contact_method").innerHTML = '+375';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("contact_method").innerHTML = '+7';
  }
}

document.getElementById("contactSelect").addEventListener("change", updateContactMethod);

document.getElementById("contactSelect").addEventListener("change", function() {
  localStorage.setItem('contactSelect', document.getElementById("contactSelect").value);
});

if (localStorage.getItem('contactSelect')) {
  document.getElementById("contactSelect").options[localStorage.getItem('contactSelect')].selected = true;
  updateContactMethod.call(document.getElementById("contactSelect"));
}
```

Comment: _Несколько слов не для протокола, а "для души"_  :D